# How do I detect tags of clicked objects in tkinter Canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, tkinter-canvas

I would like to ask how can be detected the tags in Python `tkinter.Canvas()`. I have set up a sample program with some basic canvas objects and all of them have been assigned to some tag. What I want is to get that tag value if I click on the object but have no idea how to do it.
For example when I have this code:

```
import tkinter
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=800, height=400)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_line(20, 100, 150, 350, tags="lines")
canvas.create_line(50, 20, 300, 20, tags="lines")
canvas.create_oval(200, 250, 300, 350, fill="yellow", tags="ovals")
canvas.create_oval(400, 250, 500, 350, fill="blue", tags="ovals")

for j in range(4):
    for i in range(10):
        canvas.create_rectangle(i * 70 + 10, j * 60 + 10, i * 70 + 60, j * 60 + 50, fill="lightblue", tags=f"square_{j}_{i}")

def click(coords):
    print(coords.x, coords.y)

canvas.bind("<Button-1>", click)
```

I would like to get these values such as `lines`, `ovals`, `square_5_4`, `square_7_1` etc. Does anyone have an idea how to do it please? O:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to loop through all your items in order to get the tags of your canvas items. Any item on canvas that is clicked is assigned with `"current"` tag.

You just need to use `canvas.find_withtag` along with `canvas.gettags` or pass `"current"` directly to `gettags` and it will return you all the tags associated with the canvas item.

```py
import tkinter


canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=800, height=400)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_line(20, 100, 150, 350, tags="lines")
canvas.create_oval(400, 250, 500, 350, fill="blue", tags="ovals")

for j in range(4):
    for i in range(10):
        canvas.create_rectangle(i * 70 + 10, j * 60 + 10, i * 70 + 60, j * 60 + 50, fill="lightblue", tags=f"square_{j}_{i}")

def click(event):

    #currently_clicked = canvas.find_withtag("current")
    #if currently_clicked:
    print(canvas.gettags("current")) # the first index will contain your desired output
   
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", click)
canvas.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop over all the item IDs on the canvas, get their tags and bind a function to clicking on that object (if you need that all of the objects (created before the `for` loop) on the canvas to do this):

```py
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=800, height=400)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_line(20, 100, 150, 350, tags="lines")
canvas.create_line(50, 20, 300, 20, tags="lines")
canvas.create_oval(200, 250, 300, 350, fill="yellow", tags="ovals")
canvas.create_oval(400, 250, 500, 350, fill="blue", tags="ovals")

for j in range(4):
    for i in range(10):
        canvas.create_rectangle(i * 70 + 10, j * 60 + 10, i * 70 + 60, j * 60 + 50, fill="lightblue", tags=f"square_{j}_{i}")


# loop over all items on the canvas, get their first tag (for simplicity) and bind that tag
# to clicking on the object and make that call the function that will print the tag name
# use a default value so that the correct tag is printed
for item_id in canvas.find_all():
    tag = canvas.gettags(item_id)[0]
    canvas.tag_bind(tag, '<Button-1>', lambda _, t=tag: print(t))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Matiiss [suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70423920/how-do-i-detect-tags-of-clicked-objects-in-tkinter-canvas#comment124488219_70423920) in a comment, you can use a `Canvas` object's [`tag_bind()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/canvas-methods.html) method to bind callback functions to specific events such as button 1 clicks to them. The code below — based on yours — illustrates how something like that being done.

It creates anonymous `lambda` functions that call a generic `pick()` click event handling function and passes it the original event object ***plus*** the tag name currently associated with the object.

```
import tkinter

def pick(event, tag):
    print(f'tag: {tag!r}, coords: {event.x}, {event.y}')

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=800, height=400)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_line(20, 100, 150, 350, tags='lines')
canvas.create_line(50, 20, 300, 20, tags='lines')
canvas.tag_bind('lines', '<Button-1>', lambda event: pick(event, 'lines'))

canvas.create_oval(200, 250, 300, 350, fill='yellow', tags='ovals')
canvas.create_oval(400, 250, 500, 350, fill='blue', tags='ovals')
canvas.tag_bind('ovals', '<Button-1>', lambda event: pick(event, 'ovals'))

for j in range(4):
    for i in range(10):
        tag = f'square_{j}_{i}'
        canvas.create_rectangle(i*70 + 10, j*60 + 10, i*70 + 60, j*60 + 50,
                                fill='lightblue', tags=tag)
        canvas.tag_bind(tag, '<Button-1>', lambda event, tag=tag: pick(event, tag))

tkinter.mainloop()
```